# calculating time remaining using php time()

Tags: php, time

I have a php script where I need to make sure a pre-set "future" time has not passed.

When the time is originally logged (or passed and needs relogged), I am taking:

```
$newTime = time() + 15000; // 2.5 minutes from "now"
```

The system is tossing this in the DB no problem and the numbers appear to be correct.

Now, when the page is loaded, it pulls the number from the DB and loads it into the `.php` file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$tname = $_SESSION['username']."Data";
$results = $conn->query("SELECT val FROM $tname where pri='pettyTimer'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
  //$conn declared elsewhere for connection and does work properly
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
$timer = $row['val'];
```

I am then comparing the times:

```
$now = time();
if ($timer > time()) { //script below
} else {
//more script that seems to be working fine
}
```

When the original conditional `$timer > time()` is true I am trying to break down the minutes and seconds of the time remaining and echoing them in a basic format that is readable to the user:

```
$raw = ($timer - $now);
$minutesLeft = floor($raw / 60000);
$totalMinutes2Mils = $minutesLeft * 60000;
$totalRemainingSecs = round(($raw - $totalMinutes2Mils) / (1000));

echo "You are still laying low from the last job you ran. You still have ".$minutesLeft." Minutes and ".$totalRemainingSecs." Seconds left.";
```

My problem is, the time does not appear to be shifting when I refresh/reload the page.

I echoed both `time()` and `$timer` and they are 15000 milliseconds apart when I first loaded it, so this should only exist (conditional be true) for about 2.5 minutes, but I've been working at least 5 minutes since my last set and it's still at 14 seconds.

Can someone please double check my math to make sure I'm calculating this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: `time()` returns a timestamp in __seconds__, not milliseconds. Even allowing for that, your arithmetic is all over the place. 15000 milliseconds is 15 seconds, not 2.5 minutes. 15000 seconds is a little over 4 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time() function returns the current time in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_time.asp

You are treating it as milliseconds, but should be treating it as straight seconds. take about /1000 and you should be ok.

```
$minutesLeft = floor($raw / 60);
$totalMinutes2Mils = $minutesLeft * 60;

$newTime = time() + (60*2.5); // 2.5 minutes from "now"
```

Comment: Thank you for the link - I'm not sure why I was thinking ms instead of seconds.. I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

time() returns seconds, not milliseconds, so you should add 150 instead of 15000 to get 2:30 minutes.